# How to merge two json and sort through time values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 json, my job now is to merge the two into a json and sorted by time value in the json and values ​​in json remain as originally. I have tried many ways but can not do, and you can help me? thank you.

json 1

> {"data":[{"messageString":"xin chao lqh
>   1","dateSent":"2013-06-13T02:58:37.0000000-07:00","fromUserID":"4091471","userName":"yanbi"},{"messageString":"xin
>   chao lqh
>   2","dateSent":"2013-06-13T02:58:54.0000000-07:00","fromUserID":"3569333","userName":"vuquyet"},{"messageString":"xin
>   chao lqh
>   2","dateSent":"2013-06-13T02:59:05.0000000-07:00","fromUserID":"3878204","userName":"duongdung"}]}

json 2

> {"data":[{"messageString":"Hi ban
>   h?i","toUserID":"3600311","dateSent":"2013-05-06T21:04:23.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"yes","toUserID":"4091471","dateSent":"2013-06-15T02:16:58.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"xin
>   chao
>   duongdung13","toUserID":"3844013","dateSent":"2013-06-10T21:54:56.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"xin
>   chao duongdung13 l?n 2
>   ","toUserID":"3844013","dateSent":"2013-06-10T21:55:06.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"xin
>   chao duongdung13 l?n
>   3","toUserID":"3844013","dateSent":"2013-06-10T21:55:19.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"oh
>   chào
>   yanbi","toUserID":"4091471","dateSent":"2013-06-14T23:31:38.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"yanbi
>   bi?t tôi ah
>   ?","toUserID":"4091471","dateSent":"2013-06-14T23:32:36.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"vâng
>   tôi chào
>   b?n","toUserID":"3569333","dateSent":"2013-06-14T23:42:35.0000000-07:00"},{"messageString":"sao
>   v?y b?n
>   ?","toUserID":"4091471","dateSent":"2013-06-14T23:43:45.0000000-07:00"}]}

Comment: What language? What code have you already got?

Comment: oh, Sorry. I use javascript

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery you can use `jQuery.extend(json1, json2);` more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: Thanks you, 

I tried to do as you say, but it was worth another alternative, I need the value remains the same as the original

Answer (score 0):

If the JSONs is not already parsed, you must parse them:

```
json1 = JSON.parse(json1_string);
json2 = JSON.parse(json2_string);
```

With the JSONs parsed, just concat the arrays and sort them:

```
array = json1.data.concat(json2.data);
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.dateSent < b.dateSent) {
    return -1;
  } 
  if(a.dateSent > b.dateSent) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for interest, but when I run your code, the following error occurs, you can check me one more time?

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

json1 = JSON.parse(json1_string);